# Targeted bones don't move with the rest of the armature

Tags: bones, inverse-kinematics

IK bones don't move with the rest of the armature
Ask Question
Asked today
Viewed 9 times

0

Whenever I move the main controller bone of the mesh, most of the armature moves except for the bones the IK is targeted at, and the hand bones won't move with the armature either. Like this:

[image]

If someone knows how to fix this I would love the help, thanks. Here's my blend file: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parent (*Keep Offset* mode) all the IK controllers and targets to the root bone.

Comment: That worked. Thank you.